# Можно ли скачивать файлы через apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Не нашла в документации (или не увидела), можно ли скачивать файлы через GAS? Если да, подскажите функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде, никаких проблем не должно быть

```js
function getFile_(fileURL) {
  const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fileURL);
  const fileBlob = response.getBlob();
  const folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  const result = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  return result;
}

function userActionRun() {
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTs4lzQVposg0CeIrcEHWLzcsay1lW8gq0p4-c7x-51WL37n54TvzUwhwraSb-BdZNtCJ6GLYoYr4T1/pub?gid=1270070159&single=true&output=csv';
  const file = getFile_(url);
  console.log(file.getUrl());
}
```

Comment: не понимаю, какой url должен быть в переменной const url?
Экспериментировала с разными url, но ничего не происходило

Comment: @Марина, прямая ссылка на файл. У вас она есть? Я поменял ссылку на скачивание в CSV формате листа из этой Таблицы https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KN2SuXbHN5ETss9Sj4WOTOIyxuxHUpuI_8GFewwtkBc/edit#gid=1270070159&range=A1:B16

Comment: запустила ваш скрипт и он отработал. Вопрос: файл физически куда-то скачался или я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: UPD: физически перешла по ссылке, файл скачался, но теперь не понятно, откуда эта ссылка? У таблиц вроде другой формат ссылок

Comment: @Марина, это специальная ссылка для скачивания в CSV

Comment: она генерируется вручную или автоматически можно сделать? Если вручную, подскажите, как правильно сделать её.

Comment: @Марина, и так и так

Comment: не подскажите способы генерации подобных ссылок?

Comment: @Марина, подобных чему? Каких ссылок? На какие файлы?

Comment: Мы выше обсуждали ссылки на скачивание таблиц. Вы мне сказали, что эти ссылки генерируются и в автоматическом и ручном режиме. Напомню: мне нужно знать, как вы получили ссылку, которая хранится в переменной const url

Comment: Где мы это обсуждали? Это по моей инициативе была вставлена ссылка для скачивания. Создавайте новый вопрос или просто поищите в доке. Вам нужна либо бубликация Таблиц, либо получение ссылки экспорта через API